# Drawing image on a canvas with toDataURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I have toDataURL which I want drawn on a new canvas, which is 300 by 300 in size. The image doesn't stretch over the full space provided. I want it to be stretched over the canvas fully. Even appending to a div is okay which I tried but didn't work out, it also didn't fully occupy the space.The orginal image is anyway less than 300 and 300.Also when I remove the alert code doesn't function at all.

```
   var c4 =  document.getElementById("area_c4");
   var ctx4 = c4.getContext("2d");

   var dataURL = c2.toDataURL();

   var myImg = new Image;

   myImg.src = dataURL;

   myImg.width = c4.width; // c4.width is 300px
   myImg.height = c4.height; //c4.height is 300px
   alert(c4.width);  // when I remove this alert code doesn't work
   ctx4.drawImage(myImg,0, 0 ,c4.width,c4.height); // the image doesnt strtch over 300px 300px region. It is displayed in its original size
```

Comment: Hi can you tell me how I should wait for it to load

Comment: Well it is not working

Comment: _when I remove this alert code doesn't work_ .You may need to wait for the image to load first: `var myImg = new Image; myImg.src = dataURL; myImg.onload = function() {.../*everything else goes here*/...}`

Answer (score 0):

To resize the image you will have to use the following version of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`

> [`void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage#Syntax)
>
> - **`image`**: An element to draw into the context.
> - **`sx`**: The x-axis coordinate of the top left corner of the sub-rectangle of the source `image` to draw into the destination context.
> - **`sy`**: The y-axis coordinate of the top left corner of the sub-rectangle of the source `image` to draw into the destination context.
> - **`sWidth`**: The width of the sub-rectangle of the source `image` to draw into the destination context. If not specified, the entire rectangle from the coordinates specified by `sx` and `sy` to the bottom-right corner of the image is used.
> - **`sHeight`**: The height of the sub-rectangle of the source `image` to draw into the destination context.
> - **`dx`**: The x-axis coordinate in the destination canvas at which to place the top-left corner of the source `image`.
> - **`dy`**: The y-axis coordinate in the destination canvas at which to place the top-left corner of the source `image`.
> - **`dWidth`**: The width to draw the `image` in the destination canvas. This allows scaling of the drawn image. If not specified, the image is not scaled in width when drawn.
> - **`dHeight`**: The height to draw the `image` in the destination canvas. This allows scaling of the drawn image. If not specified, the image is not scaled in height when drawn.

Also you will have to wait for the image to process the data uri before you can draw it onto the canvas. For this you can use the `load` event:

```
myImg.onload = function() {
    // here you can draw the image on the canvas
}
```

The input image in the example is 10x10 pixels wide and will be stretched to 300x300 pixels.

```js
const c4 = document.getElementById("area_c4");
var ctx4 = c4.getContext("2d");

var dataURL = "data:image/bmp;base64,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";

var myImg = new Image();
// wait until the data uri has been processed
myImg.onload = function() {
  // draw the image and scale it to the size of the canvas
  ctx4.drawImage(this,
                 0, 0, this.width, this.height, /* source */
                 0, 0, c4.width, c4.height);    /* destination */
}
myImg.src = dataURL;

/* not necessary for the solution, just to show the size of the input image */
document.getElementById("showcase").src = dataURL;
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <!-- not necessary for the solution, just to show the size of the input image -->
  Input:<br /><img id="showcase" />
</p>
<p>
  Output:<br /><canvas id="area_c4" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
</p>
```